# Why is coinbase mentioned in a BIP?

Tags: coinbase.com, terminology, coinbase-transaction, bip

I thought that BIPs were similar to Pythons PIPs. So I was confused when I read [BIP 34](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0034) mentioning coinbase explicitly. The author, Gavin Andresen, [seems not to have a connection to coinbase](https://www.linkedin.com/in/gavin-andresen-6987971/).

I thought that coinbase was just a cryptocurrency exchange, similar to Binance / Huobi / Kraken. Does coinbase have a special role? Is coinbase in some way bound to follow BIPs or did/does Gavin Andresen have influence on what coinbase does?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The coinbase mentioned in BIP34 is not the company; it is referring to the first transaction in a Bitcoin block (which is special as it is allowed to bring new currency into circulation).

Coinbase-the-company didn't even exist when BIP34 was written (or at least, wasn't known/public). The company was named after this special transaction.